# integral involving exponential with complex z

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Identify $\int _C e^z dz$ for any loop (including closed path).

My approach is since the integral of $e^z$ is $e^z$, I can use it to conclude that the answer is 0. But just not sure which corollary was used.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's Theorem? You can also prove this from the definition of integral of a continuous function over a closed path. If you path is closed the use the definition of integral of a continuous function. The integral need not be $0$ in thsi case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know Cauchy's Integral Theorem, I think that was why I said answer is 0 in closed path. But this any loop is what is confusing me, is there any value that works for any curve in this problem? If this was only restricted to closed path, then it would be 0.

Comment: The word loop refers to a closed path.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthym thanks for your follow-up! Can I just get how you would solve using integral of a continuous function over a closed path in this case? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{\gamma} f'(z)dz=\int_a^{b} f'(\gamma (t)) \gamma'(t)dt =f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a))$ for the path from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$ given by the piece-wise continuously differentiable function $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb C$. In the present case $f(z)=f'(z)=e^{z}$.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your answer, but just wondering after you used a fundamental theorem of the calculus, what was the next step you took which I am not entirely sure about.